# How to Parse JSON with PHP?

Tags: php, json

I can do a var_dump, but when trying to access the values, I am getting errors about the values not being found.

```
    {
  "metrics": {
    "timers": [
      {
        "name": "com.android.timer.launchtime",
        "startTime": 1232138988989,
        "duration_ms": 1900
      },
      {
        "name": "com.android.timer.preroll-load-time",
        "startTime": 1232138988989,
        "duration_ms": 1000
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I used the following so far to try and parse it.

```
$json_file = file_get_contents('test.json'); 
$json_a = json_decode($json_file,true);


var_dump(json_decode($json_file)); //This works

echo $json_a['name']; //I want to print the name of each (from timers).
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: have you tried to ask the VERY SAME QUESTION to google?

Comment: Just showing the JSON doesnt make your problem clear. Show the code that is throwing the error

Comment: $json_file = file_get_contents('test.json');
    $json_a = json_decode($json_file,true);


    var_dump(json_decode($json_file));
    echo '<p></p>';

    echo $json_a['name'];

Comment: @user3228624 please up-vote the answer for others help. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need do it in following manner:-

```
<?php

 $data =  '{
  "metrics": {
    "timers": [
      {
        "name": "com.android.timer.launchtime",
        "startTime": 1232138988989,
        "duration_ms": 1900
      },
      {
        "name": "com.android.timer.preroll-load-time",
        "startTime": 1232138988989,
        "duration_ms": 1000
      }
    ]
  }
}';
$new_array = json_decode($data); //convert json data into array
echo "<pre/>";print_r($new_array); //print array
foreach ($new_array->metrics->timers as $new_arr){ // iterate through array
    echo $new_arr->name.'<br/>'; // rest you can do also same   
}
?>
```

Output:- https://eval.in/407418

Comment: Why did you reposted the **exact same** answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31678502/3933332 ??

Comment: Because some insane people gives -ve mark without telling why? `Stack overflow` need to restrict it that anytime when a people give -ve mark, he have to tell the reason no matter how many points he have. @Rizier123 can you tell me how can i suggest it to Stack overflow persons?

Comment: @AK-Sonu If you have a suggestion for an improvement you probably want to post it on meta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Thanks @Rizer123. I am going to check it.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$yourDecodedJSON = json_decode($yourJson)

echo $yourDecodedJSON->metrics->timers[0]->name;
```

Or you can:

```
$yourDecodedJSON = json_decode($yourJson, true); // forces array

echo $yourDecodedJSON['metrics']['timers'][0]->name;
```

In your case, you may want to..

```
foreach($yourDecodedJSON['metrics']['timers'] as $timer){

    echo $timer['name']; echo $timer['duration_ms']; // etc

}
```

If something fails, use:

```
echo json_last_error_msg()
```

To troubleshoot further